# How to set correct hostname in Horizon?

Tags: horizon

What is the correct way to set a hostname in Horizon?

Hosting server is configured to `horizon.stellar.domain.com` but within Horizon the generated paths for all href attributes show `http://horizon/...` instead of `https://horizon.stellar.domain.com`.

On the server the HOSTNAME environment variable as well as `hostname` command return `horizon.stellar.domain.com` correctly. `/etc/sysconfig/network` contains `HOSTNAME=horizon.stellar.domain.com`.

How do I get Horizon to display the correct hostname in HTTP responses?

Comment: Not aware of a configuration parameter for it but it seems to just take the `Host` from the http request. Try `curl localhost:YourHorizonPort --header "Host: whatever"` for example. Do you have a proxy in front of your horizon that rewrites the host header?

Comment: Yes, I do and the upstream is called "horizon". Thanks! Makes sense. Will look into that. PS: I should have just kept digging in the source code but was too busy... thanks for the help.